# Detecting, moving and reading a SMS Android C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, sms

I'm currently developing an application for Android with Xamarin and Visual Studio, so I program in C #. My application must be able to receive SMS and a phone number, move the Databasse mmssms.db to store it in a temp file for example. For about two weeks of research I have found to code but the problem is that I can not at all has to operate Could you help me please.
Thank you in advance.

The code in C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Telephony;
using Environment = System.Environment;

namespace AndroidApplication4
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Label = "SMS Receiver")]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]

    public class SMSReceiver : Android.Content.BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public static readonly string INTENT_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            InvokeAbortBroadcast();
            try
            {
                if (intent.Action != INTENT_ACTION) return;

                var bundle = intent.Extras;

                if (bundle == null) return;

                var pdus = bundle.Get("pdus");
                var castedPdus = JNIEnv.GetArray(pdus.Handle);

                var msgs = new SmsMessage[castedPdus.Length];

                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                String sender = null;
                for (var i = 0; i < msgs.Length; i++)
                {
                    var bytes = new byte[JNIEnv.GetArrayLength(castedPdus[i].Handle)];
                    JNIEnv.CopyArray(castedPdus[i].Handle, bytes);

                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.CreateFromPdu(bytes);
                    if (sender == null) sender = msgs[i].OriginatingAddress;
                    sb.Append(string.Format("SMS From: {0}{1}Body: {2}{1}", msgs[i].OriginatingAddress,
                                            Environment.NewLine, msgs[i].MessageBody));
                }


                if (sender != null && sender.EndsWith("9135XXXXXX"))
                {
                    // Process our sms...
                    //        SMS.updateMessageBox("\nFrom: " + msg.getOriginatingAddress() + "\n" +
                    //"Message: " + msg.getMessageBody() + "\n");
                    /*((SMS) context).delete();*/


                    Toast.MakeText(context, "IsOrderedBroadcast :" + IsOrderedBroadcast.ToString() + "\n" + sb.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    ClearAbortBroadcast();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

AndoidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="App2.App2" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk />
    <application android:label="App2" android:icon="@drawable/Icon"></application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: If you're running on an Android version > 3.0, you need to include an Activity to launch at least once after installation to bring the app out of the _stopped_ state. Otherwise, your Receiver won't work.

Comment: What specifically are you having problems with?  You've told us your requirements and showed us some code, but haven't actually asked a specific question.

Comment: Thank you for making so fast, so I use a version higher than version 3.0. My question is why my code does not work is how to get it working. I'll try to include an activity.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You need to add the `Exported = true` parameter to the `BroadCastReceiver` attribute so it can receive messages from external sources.

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Label = "SMS Receiver", Exported=true)]
```

**2.** This is the correct code for accessing the *"pdus"* data from the `Bundle`:

```
var pdus = bundle.Get("pdus").ToArray<Java.Lang.Object>();
```

Finally, putting it all together:

```
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
public class SMSReceiver : Android.Content.BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static readonly string INTENT_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        InvokeAbortBroadcast();
        try
        {
            if (intent.Action != INTENT_ACTION) return;

            var bundle = intent.Extras;

            if (bundle == null) {
                return;
            }

            var pdus = bundle.Get("pdus").ToArray<Java.Lang.Object>();

            var msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.Length];
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            String sender = null;
            for(int i=0; i<msgs.Length; i++){

                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.CreateFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                String messageBody = msgs[i].MessageBody;

                if (sender == null) {
                    sender = msgs[i].OriginatingAddress;
                }

                sb.Append(string.Format("SMS From: {0}{1}Body: {2}{1}", msgs[i].OriginatingAddress,
                    Environment.NewLine, messageBody));
            }

            if (sender != null)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, "IsOrderedBroadcast :" + IsOrderedBroadcast.ToString() + "\n" + sb.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            else
            {
                ClearAbortBroadcast();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that this code is necessarily incorrect, but it's misleading. Each element in the `pdus` array is not a separate text message. They are parts of a single, multipart message. Additionally, because of this, you need only retrieve the originating address from one part, instead of each time through the loop. Also, there's no need to create an array of `SmsMessage`s, since you're not doing anything with more than one of the `pdus` array elements at a time.

Comment: @MikeM. It's a straight, compileable conversion of the code the OP originally provided in order to make it work (broadcast receiver gets trigger and content can be read). My concern wasn't the correctness of the original behaviour, rather making sure that OP had a working example of their original code to build from.

Comment: Understood. I was merely pointing it out because this not-quite-correct code continues to circulate because people blindly copy answers on SO without ever testing them, and then post the same code in their own answers, which again gets blindly copied without testing, etc. Remember, your answer isn't here for just the OP, but for all the future users who might see this post. Just a note. Cheers!

Comment: Hello thank you for all these answers and I'm really grieve for the delay I have some small problems with anything. My program finally works with your help, but my problem now and always receives an error message that is "Cannot cast from source type to destination type" regardless of the phone number. So I think it is a problem to redirect SMS but I'm not sure I know how please we do could you help me to solve this problem.